# iOS: adMob for universal App?

Tags: ios, admob

I am implementing adMob ads into my Universal App. In the www.admob.com, it has two options for ads: one for iPad app and one for iPhone app. My question is that do I have to make to two different ads with two different publisher IDs for my universal app or just make one ads with one publisher ID for my app and then change the ads size inside the code? Thank you

Comment: what is problem with my question? someone votes down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can do either. If you want finer level tracking to easily see what's coming in from your iPhone version compared to your iPad version you may want to use 2 ID's, but using just a universal one that you change in code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

2 separate side/app's will give you more flexibility, like mediation settings.

Tip:
Create 2 separate  side/app's.
You will now have 2 publisher id's.
Make sure you select the correct publisher id in 
Sites & AppsAd > Network Mediation > Edit: AdMob Network